# (co)homology of symmetric groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $S_n=\{\text{bijections }[n]\to[n]\}$ be the n-th symmetric group. Its (co)homology will be understood with trivial action. What are the $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $H_k(S_n;\mathbb{Z})$? Using GAP, we calculate this for small $n$ and $k$:
[image]
This seems to be an infinite amount of data with no apparent patterns, just the stabilization for $n\geq2k$.

In *Stable homology of automorphism groups of free groups* (Galatius - 2008) p.2 there is written:
"The homology groups $H_k(S_n)$ are completely known" referring to Nakaoka's articles
*Decomposition Theorem for Homology Groups of Symmetric Groups*, *Homology of the Infinite Symmetric Group*, *Note on cohomology algebras of symmetric groups* from 1960, 1961, 1962. I haven't found any such table in those articles, or in *Cohomology of Finite Groups* (Adem, Milgram - 1994). My questions are:

1) Does $H_k(S_n;\mathbb{Q})$ and $H_k(S_n;\mathbb{Z}_p)$ for all prime $p$ determine $H_k(S_n;\mathbb{Z})$?

**2)** How does the above table look for larger n and k, e.g. what is $H_k(S_{2k};\mathbb{Z})$ for $k=1,...,30$?

3) Is for every prime $p$ and $k\geq1$ the module $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ a direct summand of some $H_k(S_n;\mathbb{Z})$?

4) Does $H_k(S_n;R)\cong H_k(S_{2k};R)$ as $R$-modules for $n>2k$ hold over any ring $R$?

Comment: On cohomology, the depth of torsion seems to be tied to a transfer product, and a corresponding divided powers structure on it, which along with cup product give a Hopf ring structure which sheds considerable light on multiplicative and Steenrod structure.  (See my and Guerra's papers on cohomology of symmetric groups.)  I haven't worked this out and written it up, but I can share the idea easily enough if you'd like to e-mail me.  Guerra, Salvatore and I are writing up the divided powers part of the story as part of studying DX and CX now.

Answer (score 22):

The paradoxical answer is that it is annoying but straightforward to determine $H_k(S_n)$
for particular values of $k$ and $n$, but it is very easy to write down $H_*(\coprod BS_n)$,
encompassing all $k$ and all $n$ at once.   More generally, if $C$ is the monad on based spaces
$X$ determined by any $E_{\infty}$ operad $\mathcal C$, then the Hopf algebra 
$H_*(CX;\mathbb F_p)$ is an explicitly known functor of the coalgebra $H_*(X;\mathbb F_p)$.  Moreover the Bockstein spectral sequence 
of $CX$ for any prime $p$ is functorially determined by that of $X$, so in principal the integral 
homology of $CX$ is explicitly determined by the integral homology of $X$.  When $X= S^0$, $CX$ is 
the disjoint union of the classifying spaces $BS_n$, so the homology of all symmetric groups is
there as a special case, connected together by multiplicative structure determined by the the evident 
homomorphisms $S_m\times S_n \longrightarrow S_{m+n}$.  User43326 gives a reference for all of this.
The answer to 1) and 3) is yes, the answer to 2) is that it is boring but implicit how to write down a 
table such as yours for small values of $n$ and $k$, it is just not especially interesting to do so, or so it
seems to me.  It can be left as an exercise to check whether or not 4) is true.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "straightforward to determine $H_k(S_n)$"? Is there a combinatorial description? Also, where can one find the proof of 3)?

Comment: If you have a polynomial algebra on a specified set of generators in specified degrees, finitely many in each degree, then you can enumerate.  Mod p, that kind of enumeration is immediate from the functor I alluded to.  The proof of 3) is in the description of the Bockstein spectral sequences I alluded to, pages 48-49 opus cit.

Comment: $H_*(CS^0;Z/p)$ is a polynomial algebra with generators $Q^I(i_0)$'s where $Q^I$'s are allowable Dyer-Lashof operations.  Assign weight $p^l(I)$ where $l(I)$ is the length of $I$ to the element $Q^I(i_0)$.  Then monominals of weight $n$ form a basis of $H_*(\Sigma _n;Z/p)$.

Comment: User 43326, that is not quite right for odd p.  You forgot the bocksteins in the DL operations, which give you odd degree generators, so you have a polynomial algebra on even degree generators tensored with an exterior algebra on odd degree generators.  Change polynomial algebra to free (graded) commutative algebra and the statement is correct.

Comment: a related question and some possible corrections: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297319/

Answer (score 17):

The answer to the question 1) is "yes".  The classifying space of the symmetric group is of finite type, so its integral homology is determined by its rational homology and $p$-local homology for all $p$'s. Now, mod $p$ homology doesn't really determine the $p$-local homology, but we know completely the bockstein spectral sequence (see http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf Chapter 1, Theorem 4.13, so we can get the $p$-local homology. Furthermore, since the symmetric group is finite, its rational homology is trivial.

The answer to the question 4) is also yes (and this time, it is a real yes), and a good reference is http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf You can read off 
mod $p$ homology of $\Sigma _n$ from that of $CS^0$, and this is treated in chapter 1, section 5.

Hopefully you can find the answers to other questions in the references above.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some comments, including an answer to (3).  Firstly, if you want an actual explicit computation of the mod-2 cohomology of symmetric groups $S_n$ for as large an $n$ as possible, you should look at M. Feshbach's `The mod-2 cohomology rings of the symmetric groups and invariants' Topology volume 41 (2002) 57-84.  This contains explicit computations of the cohomology rings $H^*(S_n;\mathbb{F}_2)$ for $n\leq 16$, including correcting a minor error in a calculation in the book of A Adem and J Milgram.

The advantage of cohomology is that it is a ring, also that the cohomology of a finite group with coefficients in either $\mathbb{Z}$ or a field is a finitely presented algebra over the coefficients.

Here is a non-constructive solution to (3).  By the universal coefficient theorem, it suffices to show the same thing for cohomology.  Now let $n$ be sufficiently large that the symmetric group $S_n$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $p^k$; of course the least such $n$ is $n=p^k$.  For any such $n$, there will be elements of order $p^k$ in $H^j(S_n;\mathbb{Z})$ for infinitely many values of $j$.  To see this one uses the Evens-Venkov theorem.

For any finite group $G$ and any subgroup $H$, the map from $H^*(G;\mathbb{Z})$ to $H^*(H;\mathbb{Z})$ makes the ring $H^*(H;\mathbb{Z})$ into a module for the ring $H^*(G;\mathbb{Z})$.  The Evens-Venkov theorem tells us that $H^*(H;\mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated as an $H^*(G;\mathbb{Z})$-module.

Now to apply this.  The cohomology ring of the cyclic group of order $p^k$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[c]/(p^kc)$, where $c$ is a generator for $H^2$.  If $R$ is a (graded) subring of this ring such that the whole ring is a finitely generated $R$-module, then $R$ contains $c^m$ for some $m$, and hence $H^{2mj}(S_n;\mathbb{Z})$ contains an element of order $p^k$ for every $j$.  The universal coefficient theorem then tells you that $H_{2mj-1}(S_n;\mathbb{Z})$ contains an element of order $p^k$ for all $j$.

You asked about summands of order exactly $p^k$.  In fact, $H^*(S_n;\mathbb{Z})$ will contain these whenever $n\geq p^k$, although I can't provide a quick argument.  A quicker thing to see is that for $p^k \leq n < p^{k+1}$, the exponent of the $p$-local cohomology of $S_n$ is exactly $p^k$.  I'll give the argument just for $n=p^k$.  There is a subgroup of $S_{p^k}$ isomorphic to the direct product of $p$ copies of $S_{p^{k-1}}$.  Furthermore, the index of this subgroup is divisible by $p$ but not divisible by $p^2$.

For any finite group $G$ and subgroup $H$, there is a transfer map in cohomology $H^*(H;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^*(G;\mathbb{Z})$ with the property that the composite map from $H^*(G;\mathbb{Z})$ to itself given by first mapping to $H^*(H;\mathbb{Z})$ and then transferring back up is equal to multiplication by the index $|G:H|$.

Going back to the symmetric group, we know by induction on $k$ that the exponent of the $p$-part of $H^*(S_{p^{k-1}};\mathbb{Z})$ is $p^{k-1}$, and by the Kunneth formula the same holds true for the direct product of $p$ copies of this group.  The restriction from $S_{p^k}$ down to this subgroup, followed by the transfer map back up is, up to units, multiplication by $p$ on the $p$-local cohomology $H^*(S_{p^k};\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})$.  Hence the exponent of this group is at most $p^k$.  Combined with the Evens-Venkov lower bound this gives the claim.