# Group (Co)Homology of Symmetric Group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, finite-groups, kt.k-theory-and-homology, group-cohomology

The question concerns the group homology or group cohomology of symmetric groups.

1. The entries in [groupprops.subwiki.org](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_cohomology_of_symmetric_group:S4) and in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180637) show the results for the symmetric group S$_4$.

[groupprops.subwiki.org](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_cohomology_of_symmetric_group:S4), $H_q(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{Z})$:
[image]

[this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180637), $H_k(\text{S}_{n=4},\mathbb{Z})$:
[image]

2. If the [groupprops.subwiki.org](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_cohomology_of_symmetric_group:S4) has the correct result, is it correct to say that the **torsion** parts of Group (Co)Homology of Symmetric Group are related by:

$$H^q(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=H_q(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{Z})?$$

Thus,
$$H^1(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=H_1(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2?$$
$$H^2(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=H_2(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2?$$
$$H^3(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=H_3(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3?$$
$$H^4(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=H_4(\text{S}_4,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2?$$

3. More generally, do we have a **precise relation** between the group cohomology and group homology of different coefficients:

$$H^q(G,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) \text { and } H_p(G,\mathbb{Z}),$$
say for any finite group $G$, and here in particular $\text{S}_4$? (Here $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}=S^1=$U(1).)

Comment: + 1, Jeremy Rickard, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Since symmetric groups are finite groups, its (co)homology is entirely torison (except in $H_0$.

Comment: Just in case my previous comment was not clear enough: $R/Z$ is injective, so in the universal coefficient theorem's statement, there is no $Ext ^1$ term, so you only get $Hom$ term.  However, for any torsion abelian group $A$ you have $Hom(A,R/Z)\cong A$ in a non-canonical way.

Comment: @  user43326, Thanks so much +1. then, am I correct about my statements in part 2, after all? How about the part 3? [Feel free to write an answer - it will not have to be demanding one.]

Comment: @user43326 it's false (that $Hom(A,R/Z)$ is isomorphic to $A$ for $A$ torsion abelian). Two counterexamples (among others) (a) if $A=\bigoplus A_n$ with $A_n\neq 0$ finite, then $A$ is countable, while $Hom(A,R/Z)\simeq\prod_n A_n$, which is uncountable. (b) if $A=\mathbf{Z}[1/n]/\mathbf{Z}$, then $Hom(A,R/Z)\simeq\mathbf{Z}_n$, which is torsion-free (and also uncountable). Actually when $A$ is infinite countable, it's always uncountable.

Comment: @YCor Yes, you are right,  I wanted to say for $A$ finite abelian.

Comment: @wonderich The third question is just Pontrjagin duality.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, let $X$ be a space (with usual nice properties).  Then 
as ${\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}$ is injective, the universal coefficient theorem for cohomology gives an isomorphism
$$Hom (H_*(X,{\mathbb Z}) ,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z})
\cong H^*(X,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}). $$
Now, when $X$ is the classifying space of a finite group $BG$, in positive dimension, $A=H_*(X,{\mathbb Z})$ is finite abelian group, thus there is non-canonical isomorphism between $A$ and $Hom(A,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z})$.

Thus the answer to the third question (which includes the second one) is "yes".